# How to configure the dynamic database for the formbuilder

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, jndi, orbeon

How to handle dynamic database  for form builder. Which way I need to configure the Data Base source name in "context.xml" from the tomcat and "Orbeon forms" are stored in single "orbeon" static db.

As of now I am using the following context in the **context.xml** and it access the static DB and then create/update/delete the forms.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
initialSize="3" maxActive="10" maxIdle="20" maxWait="30000" 
driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" 
poolPreparedStatements="true" 
validationQuery="select 1 " 
testOnBorrow="true" 
username="orbeon" 
password="orbeon" 
url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:3306/orbeon?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8"/>
```

Here "orbeon" is the static DB.

Instead of static DB I need to give a Dynamic DB. Before user open the form builder "**URL**" I given login page. If authentication is success then based on the userid user can access the forms his DB only.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically change the database for a single connection - and you shouldn't do that for connections that come from a pool anyway.

In Postgres it's probably better to have multiple schemas in a **single** database - one schema for each user.

Then after you get the connection from the connection pool, you can change the default schema for the session using:

```
set search_path = user_specific_schema;
```

Don't forget to commit this change, otherwise the first rollback in the session would revert this. You can either do that by running that statement with auto commit on, or calling `commit()` on your `Connection` object.

You might be able to make this happen automatically by using an [interceptor](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#JDBC_interceptors) for your connection pool.

Comment: thank you for the reply but i still didn't get the idea how to change the schema dynamically based on different users.Can you please describe it little more.thanx in advance.

Comment: @Prathyush You change the schema using the SQL statement in my answer. There is nothing more to it

Comment: Can you please tell me where I need to execute the schema in the orbeon form builder source code.

Comment: @Prathyush: sorry, I have no idea what that orbeon thing is.